# c++ allocation on the stack acting curiously

Tags: c++, oop, stackalloc

Curious things with g++ (maybe also with other compilers?):

```
struct Object {
        Object() { std::cout << "hey "; }
        ~Object() { std::cout << "hoy!" << std::endl; }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
        {
                Object myObjectOnTheStack();
        }
        std::cout << "===========" << std::endl;
        {
                Object();
        }
        std::cout << "===========" << std::endl;
        {
                Object* object = new Object();
                delete object;
        }
}
```

Compied with g++:

```
===========
hey hoy!
===========
hey hoy!
```

**The first type of allocation does not construct the object**. What am I missing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The first type of *construction* is not actually constructing the object.  In order to create an object on the stack using the default constructor, you must omit the `()`'s

```
Object myObjectOnTheStack;
```

Your current style of definition instead declares a function named myObjectOnTheStack which returns an `Object`.

Comment: Try `Object myObjectOnTheStack;` ie without the `()`

Comment: …"instead *declares* a function"…

Answer (score 4):

Yet another example of the "most vexing parse". Instead of defining an object, you've declared a function named `myObjectOnTheStack` that takes no arguments and returns an `Object`.

Answer (score 2):

```
Object myObjectOnTheStack();
```

is a forward declaration of a function `myObjectOnTheStack` taking no parameters and returning an `Object`.

What you want is

```
Object myObjectOnTheStack;
```